# Issue with record length when creating CSV in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv, sqlcmd

I am experiencing an issue when generating a csv file from SQLCMD. I have a test table which looks like this.

Which has 2 numeric columns and 2 nvarchar columns (one 64 characters long and the other 2000 characters long).

If I issue the command `select * from test` what I get is this

```
number1 number2 varcharacter1   varcharacter2
1   2   test    longertext
2   3   test2   longertext2
3   4   test3   longertext3
```

If I want to output this as csv I use this sql:

```
select cast(number1 as nvarchar) + ',' +
    varcharacter2  + ',' + 
    varcharacter1  + ',' +
    cast(number2 as nvarchar)
from test
```

This gives me this which looks OK

```
(No column name)
1,longertext,test,2
2,longertext2,test2,3
3,longertext3,test3,4
```

The issue is when I enter it via SQLCMD. If I issue the following command

```
Scripts>sqlcmd -S localhost\STUDIO -d studiodb -U sa  -P Studio2016! -h-1 -i test.sql -o test.csv
```

What I get is a CSV file which contains the data, but when I open it in TextPad the last column is padded out to 2000 characters long.

```
1,longertext,test,2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

2,longertext2,test2,3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

3,longertext3,test3,4
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The reason it's doing that isn't that's it's padding the last field out, it's that you're passing out 1 field which contains commas. One of those fields is an `nvarchar(2000)`, so due to data type precedence, it has the highest. This means your string becomes something like an `nvarchar(2050)`, and hence the padding at the end.

Comment: Theres, actually no need to do it the way you have done. Have a look at https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/25/sql-server-export-data-as-csv-from-database-using-sqlcmd/. SQLCMD supports exporting to a csv natively.